# cloudant Java Client getDocsAs()

Tags: java, cloudant

I am trying to use the Java Client API, specifically `getViewRequestBuilder` with `getDocAs()`

My Cloudant data looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "30984feadf2246a68d97cbeff8bf06a0",
  "_rev": "1-8df71f2f874f9228fffb831779063fa9",
  "correlationID": "qweriwern34924df02342jk33",
  "status": "Received",
  "contactType": "EMAIL",
  "ttlHours": 0,
  "requestingId": "123456",
  "requestingApplication": "JUnit",
  "logTimeMs": 1466446389064,
  "logTimeString": "20-06-2016 14:13:09",
  "tsdHitStatus": false,
  "emailContact": {
    "to": "bob@foo,com",
    "bcc": "jane@foo.com"
  },
  "sendSecure": false
}
```

I created a view to return three fields.

```
if ( doc. emailContact.to && doc.correlationID) {   
  emit(doc.logTimeMs, 
    {
    correlationID:  doc.correlationID,
    emailAddress: doc.emailContact.to,
    contactType: doc.contactType
    });
```

I am trying to get query based on a time range and return a email object. The view works fine from PostMan. When I try this from Java I get two of the fields, but emailAddress field is always null. I am wondering if the `getDocAs()` fails to understand the "doc.emailContact.to" field.

I thought the line "emailAddress: doc.emailContact.to," in the view would allow the mapping between the data and the class.

The Java code to get the data from the view:

```
db.getViewRequestBuilder("ch_queries","Email).newRequest(Key.Type.NUMBER, Object.class).startKey(time0).endKey(time1).includeDocs(true).reduce(false).build().getResponse().getDocsAs(Email.class);
```

Email class

```
public class Email  implements Serializable {

    private String correlationID;
    private String emailAddress;
    private String contactType;

    public String getContactType() {
        return contactType;
    }
    public void setContactType(String contactType) {
        this.contactType = contactType;
    }
    public String getCorrelationID() {
        return correlationID;
    }
    public void setCorrelationID(String correlationID) {
        this.correlationID = correlationID;
    }
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this isn't working as you expect is because you are attempting to get the document that you have included in the view results as the an instance of `Email`. So the first thing to do is remove `includeDocs(true)` from your query.

Next what you should be doing is typing the ViewRequest to

```
ViewResponse<Integer, Email> response;
response =   db.getViewRequestBuilder("ch_queries","Email")
               .newRequest(Key.Type.NUMBER,Email.class)
               .startKey(time0)
               .endKey(time1)
               .reduce(false)
               .build()
               .getResponse()
```

You can than iterate over the response using the enhanced for-loop like so:

```
for (ViewResponse.Row<Integer, Email> row : response.getRows()) {
    Email email = row.getValue();
}
```